# return week number based on date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am new to T-SQL and needed urgent assistance here.
I am trying to get the week number from a given date.

I understand that there is a build in function for it but the value return is not exactly what I wanted.

For e.g., by using select `datepart(wk, '2013-01-07')`, it would return me '2'.. but the actually fact is it should return '1' instead of '2'.

Any ideas how to correct this issue?

Comment: *When datepart is week (wk, ww) or weekday (dw), the return value depends on the value that is set by using SET DATEFIRST.*

Comment: select datediff(dd, '2013-01-01', '2013-01-07') / 7

Comment: You need to define exactly what ***you*** mean by the week number.  Monday to Sunday, Saturday to Friday?  If the last day of the week is on Jan 1st, how do you handle it?  1st Jan becomes part of the last week of the previous year?  Week 1 becomes 1 day long?  Etc, etc.  you need to be ALOT more specific about your needs and expectations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dy` *datepart* specifier to get *dayOfYear* number and divide it by 7:

```
select (datepart(dy, '2013-01-05') - 1) / 7 + 1;
```

Working [**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/7294).

Comment: +1 yes, I thought to suggest datediff with January first, but this one better I think

Answer (score 0):

Try this

SELECT DATEPART(WEEK,GETDATE())

Answer (score 0):

This depends on hop you define the *first* week.  Does it always start on the same weekday? or does it always start on the first of January? If you want it to always start on the same weekday, then use `Set datefirst` to tell T-SQL what weekdaty you want to define as the start of the week.  If you want it to always start on Jan 1, then just use day of year instead of week, subtract 1, integer divide by 7 and add 1.

```
declare @dat DateTime = getdate()
Select Select (datepart(dy, @dat)-1) / 7 + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Although going from memory, I believe the ISO standard for the first week of the year is the week in the year that the first Thursday of the year is in. This would possibly explain why the built in function gives a result different to that you require.